# How to create and empty JSON in JavaScript and add keys and additional JSON objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json

How to create and empty JSON in JavaScript and add keys and additional JSON objects dynamically?

```
mydata = {}
```

to

```
newdata = {
       'first': [ {'1': 'test'} ]
}
```

I tried this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const myJSON = '{}';
myJSON['first']['1'] = 'test';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);

let text = "";
for (const x in myObj) {
  text += x + ", ";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json into an object, then set his properties

```js
const myJSON = '{}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
myObj['first'] = [{'1':'test'}];

console.log(myObj);
newdata = {
       'first': [ {'1': 'test'} ]
}
```

Comment: I want key "first" dynamically added.. "first", "second", "third". Then add more keys into each array "1", "2", "3"....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var newData = { first: [{ 1: "test" }] };

//or 

const myJson = {};
myJson["first"]= [];
var newItem={ "1": "test" };
myJson["first"].push(newItem);
myJson["second"]= [];
newItem={ "2": "test" };
myJson["second"].push(newItem);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```